# How do I enable memory zone reclaim mode on the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, gentoo

I am running Gentoo Linux Hardened using kernel 4.3.3-hardened-r4 on an AMD A4-5300 APU. To troubleshoot a memory problem I have with my system I need to enable `sysctl vm.zone_reclaim_mode=1`, but doing so results in the following error message:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode: No such file or directory
```

Being this Gentoo, that error message probably means I missed compiling some kernel feature. However, I looked around on the kernel's configuration menu (`make menuconfig`) and couldn't find any option, and the internet wasn't conclusive at all when looking up online how to enable this option. The closest thing I could find was [this Linux kernel's documentation page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) that explains all the configuration files located under `/proc/sys/vm`.

What do I have to do to be able to use `vm.zone_reclaim_mode=1`?

Comment: have you NUMA enabled in your kernel configuration?

Comment: Apparently not. I just went over the NUMA-related options and found CONFIG_NUMA disabled. I just enabled it and my kernel is currently compiling.

Comment: Enabling CONFIG_NUMA worked like a charm. Mind if you post it as an answer to this question?

Comment: I would like to post it as an answer and I will try to do so as soon as I will know better how NUMA is related with zone_reclaim_mode :) ... For now it was just a good intuition.

Comment: The kernel documentation linked above says "zone_reclaim may be enabled if it's known that the workload is partitioned such that each partition fits within a NUMA node". My reading comprehension is limited here because I don't know much about memory handling on AMD64 and Linux, but it mentions working with NUMA so I guess if NUMA is not supported then there won't be any zone reclaim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question since it hasn't gotten any answer and the solution suggested on the comments worked like a charm.

I solved this by enabling `CONFIG_NUMA` in my kernel configuration and rebuilding it. After booting my new kernel I could enable `sysctl vm.zone_reclaim_mode=1` without a hitch.